# How to get the Value of Attributes in HTML tags using PHP

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I have a string such like

```
$str = '<a href="http://www.example.com/example_link">This is the Example Link</a>';
```

I want to get the href value `(http://www.example.com/example_link)` and the text value `(This is the Example Link)` from the above string in php

How can I get these values from the string, Any Efficient way. Do I need to use PHP DOM or REGEX?

Note: There could be more than one occurrences of an anchor `<a>` tag in a string.

Comment: You need regular expression and `preg_match_all`. The pattern is something like `/<\S+\s(([a-zA-Z]+)=(["\'])([^\\3])\\3)+\>/`. I\m not completely sure about backreferences (`\\3`), you can try using just `"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that your string will be in properly xml formatted then you can use
[simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

try this

```
<?php
$str = '<a href="http://www.example.com/example_link">This is the Example Link</a>';
$xml  = simplexml_load_string($str);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
 ?>
```

it will return you a object and you can access whatever you want

[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/CJPPVm)

Answer (score 0):

**First find the link**

> `
>   // The Regular Expression filter
>   $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\://[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?/";
>   // The Text you want to filter for urls
>   $text = '[This is the Example Link](http://www.example.com/example_link)';
>   // Check if there is a url in the text
>   if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
>          $link=$url[0];
>   } else {
>          $link='Some problem occured';
>   }

**Now find the text between the anchors**

> `$link_text = preg_replace('/<a.*?>/i', '', $text);
>
>   $link_text = preg_replace('/<\/a>/i', '', $link_text);
>
>   ?>`